# Bulk publish pages in BetterCms

Tags: c#, bettercms

I have been adding pages in bettercms as unpublished, and now have hundreds of pages to publish by hand.  Is there a way to bulk publish a lot of pages at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently BetterCMS does not support actions for multiple pages, but this is very nice idea.

I've added to the backlog https://github.com/devbridge/BetterCMS/issues/1327 and will let you know if this will be available in near future.